# Composer autoloader

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to learn composer, but I can't seem to get the autoloader to work with a package I've created. It just states that the class could not be found.

What am I doing wrong?

Index.php:

```
require 'vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php';
use packageName\core\Bootstrap;
$boot = new Bootstrap();
```

Bootstrap.class.php (inside /vendor/vendorName/packageName/core/):

```
namespace packageName\core;
class Bootstrap {
   ...
```

composer.json for packageName:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "packageName\\core\\": "/vendor/vendorName/packageName/core" }
}
```

Comment: Just include vendor/autoload.php, https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: Is `/vendor/...` really at root level in your filesystem? If it's a relative path rather than an absolute path, use `"vendor/vendorName/packageName/core"`

Comment: It doesn't work with vendor/autoload.php either. I don't think it finds the files. And /vendor/ is at the root level.

Comment: Composer recommends vendor/packageName for library name formatting.
Do us ./vendor/autoloader.php as the root class auto loader. Also, remember to run composer -o after changing classname/spaces so that the classmap is rebuilt. Next up: `use vendor/packageName/className` at the top of Bootstrap.class.php. Let us know what happens (exact error msg please).

Comment: @Pheagey The problem was actually solved. It was a relative/absolute path issue on my side (the accepted answer). Thx anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark Baker's answer (in the comments above) fixed the problem.

> "Is /vendor/... really at root level in your filesystem? If it's a relative path rather than an absolute path, use "vendor/vendorName/packageName/core"

Answer (score 1):

First: Don't include a random autoload component. [Composer has documentation how to use the autoloader](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading).

Second: Don't deal with packages that are already installed with Composer in your OWN autoloading. Everything that is inside the `vendor` folder must not be autoloaded from within your own `composer.json` - it should supply it's own autoloading definition. The easiest case would be you having only this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "vendorName/packageName" : "^1.0"
    }
}
```

You would only need to [add autoloading](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload) to this if you want to have your own code autoloaded as well (which I would recommend).

Comment: I'm creating a package. It consists of some files, that all need to be loaded at start.

Comment: But if your package uses other packages, these must not appear in the autoloading of your own package. Additionally, the only reason for a file to be loaded at the start would be if it contains a function, because functions cannot be autoloaded. I think you should give a better example of what you are about to do - and please also add the complete error message, don't paraphrase it.

Comment: My package does not use any other package. I'm testing out if my package, here called "packageName" can be autoloaded when installed by others. I need the bootstrap() class to run at start.

Comment: What is that bootstrap class doing? According to PSR standards, a file SHOULD NOT do both declare new symbols (classes, functions, constants) and at the same time cause side effects. Composer would allow running a file if you put it as `"files"` autoloader, but forcing a bootstrapping upon every user of a package should be deliberate decision - I wouldn't like it and suspect there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Yes, I'm almost sure there is a better way to do it. The package is suppose to be an MVC engine, with bootstrap to get the request URI (i.e. site.com/Controller/method) and run the right controller. But I have created a custom include.php that includes the right files instead of running autoload, until I've read up and really understand the whole package/composer deal. Thanks anyways, Sven!